# How to write to Django FileField from a tempfile?

Tags: python, django, temporary-files, rasterio

I am processing an image within a Django app. I used rasterio to process the geospatial image. I want to save the output directly to a FileField in a Model. I used a tempfile to write the output from rasterio, and used the method `Model.FileField.save` to hopefully write it with a reference to my Model instance.

I have a simple model:

```
class MaskedLayer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='masked',
        null=True,
        max_length=500)
```

In my tasks, however this is an example:

```
from celery import shared_task
import rasterio
import tempfile

from app.models import MaskedLayer


@shared_task
def process_image():

    mask_layer_name = 'processed_image.tif'
    masked_layer = MaskedLayer.objects.create()

    with rasterio.open('example.tif') as dataset: # only example of reading/processing of image
        out_image = dataset.read()

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
        tmpfile.write(out_image)

        with rasterio.open(tmpfile.name) as dataset:
            masked_layer.file.save(mask_layer_name, File(dataset))


    pass
```

I get this response. I am not sure of the error. Feel free to use the **[example file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12p_XBz1WvNXeUCCGptnvjgnT3-9AluUe?usp=share_link)**.

> Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault
>
> Current thread 0x00007f453b463740 (most recent call first):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line
> 232 in get_traceback_frame_variables   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line
> 544 in get_exception_traceback_frames   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line
> 490 in get_traceback_frames   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line
> 320 in get_traceback_data   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line
> 403 in get_traceback_text   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line
> 125 in emit   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/**init**.py",
> line 978 in handle   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/**init**.py", line 1706 in
> callHandlers   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/**init**.py",
> line 1644 in handle   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/**init**.py", line 1634 in _log
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/**init**.py", line 1518 in
> error   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line
> 241 in log_response   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 143 in response_for_exception   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 57 in inner   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
> line 136 in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 55 in inner   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
> line 136 in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 55 in inner   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
> line 136 in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 55 in inner   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
> line 136 in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 55 in inner   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
> line 136 in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 55 in inner   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
> line 136 in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 55 in inner   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
> line 136 in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 55 in inner   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 140 in get_response   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line
> 258 in get_response   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line
> 153 in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line
> 805 in request   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line
> 238 in request   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line
> 286 in request   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line
> 541 in generic   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line
> 234 in generic   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line
> 210 in post   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line
> 296 in post   File
> "/usr/src/app/data_management/tests/test_data_management.py", line 18
> in test_solar_pot   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/case.py",
> line 579 in _callTestMethod   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/case.py", line 623 in run   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/case.py", line 678 in **call**
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py",
> line 416 in _setup_and_call   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py",
> line 381 in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 122 in run   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 84 in **call**
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/runner.py", line 217 in run
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/runner.py",
> line 980 in run_suite   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line
> 1058 in run_tests   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py",
> line 68 in handle   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 448 in execute   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 402 in run_from_argv   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py",
> line 24 in run_from_argv   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 440 in execute   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 446 in execute_from_command_line   File "/usr/src/app/manage.py",
> line 18 in main   File "/usr/src/app/manage.py", line 22 in
>
> Extension modules: psycopg2._psycopg, numpy.core._multiarray_umath,
> numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg,
> numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common,
> numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers,
> numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox,
> numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator,
> rasterio._version, rasterio._err, rasterio._filepath, rasterio._env,
> rasterio._transform, rasterio._base, rasterio.crs, rasterio._features,
> rasterio._warp, rasterio._io, fiona._err, fiona._geometry,
> fiona._shim, fiona._env, fiona.schema, fiona.ogrext, fiona._crs
> (total: 31)

Answer (score 1):

I am by far not familiar with `rasterio` and `celery` but let me show you my working implementation as guidance:

```py
import io
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

def _upload_location(instance, filename):
    return f'/some/path/{filename}'

class MyModel(models.Model):
    model_image_field = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=_upload_location, editable=False)

    def save_structure_img(self):
        tmp_img = io.BytesIO()  # create buffer
        structure_img = self.create_structure_img() # create img 
        structure_img.save(tmp_img, 'PNG')  # utilize save method of your image to save it to the buffer
        name = "your_wanted_filename"  # create a name
        self.model_image_field.save(f'{name}.png', ImageFile(tmp_img)) # save buffer to model_image field
```

I know, I edited out the creation of `structure_img` but that should not matter, because it is specific to my project.

Let me try to translate this to your usecase:

```py
import io
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

@shared_task
def process_image():

    mask_layer_name = 'processed_image.tif'
    masked_layer = MaskedLayer.objects.create()

    with rasterio.open('example.tif') as dataset: # only example of reading/processing of image
        out_image = dataset.read()
    
    tmp_img = io.BytesIO() # create buffer
    out_image.save(tmp_img, 'PNG')
    # i hope this is the right place where out_image has a `.save` method.
    name = "your_wanted_filename"
    
    masked_layer.field.save(f'{name}.png', ImageFile(tmp_img))
    pass
```

Also I admit that I have no clue what your proposed error is trying to tell me. But I feel like the database is complaining about what you are trying to insert. If you so search for an answer how to fix exactly that error, my answer is not what you are looking for. It is more of an alternative approach to the same solution.